# Textview fill available width

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

i have two textviews in relative layout. first textview size is fixed and second textview size is dynamic. I want my second textview to fill all available width [want output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48TQB.png)but i am unable to do this. is it possible? [this is what i am getting right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adiqo.png)

My xml :

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp">

        <com.staff_have_says.utitlies.MyTextViewBold
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Massage To Management"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
         />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/banner"
            android:text="Flaticon Basic License. It's necessary to credit the author.  How to credit the authorship of the icons?Flaticon Basic License. It's necessary to credit the author.  How to credit the authorship of the icons?"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your `xml` code.

Comment: @jaydroider i have posted that.check edited.

Comment: You can't build that with 2 separate TextViews. Try a SpannableString for instance. Something like pawegio mentioned below.

Comment: @mike tried that but not getting desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single `TextView` for both sections of your content with `SpannableString` as a text. See [example](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.com/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html).

Comment: thanks. i followed your method and i am able to achieve the desired ouput but how to set padding to background color span.

Comment: my code: String resposne="Flaticon Basic License. It's necessary to 
               author.  How to credit the authorship of the icons?";

        SpannableString styledString
                = new SpannableString("Massage To Management-"+resposne);
        styledString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, 21, 0);
        styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, 21, 0);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.banner);
        textView.setText(styledString);

Comment: It requires custom `ReplacementSpan` with access to `draw()` method. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29023947/1432752).

Comment: tried that but not working. texts are not in proper place and some text are hiding behind background color.

Comment: Working well for single line text but not for multi line texts.